# What are the benefits of explicitly rendering reCAPTCHA widget as opposed to automatically rendering?

Tags: captcha, recaptcha

Google's reCPATCHA V2 widget can be rendered automatically or explicitly, as it says on this page: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display.

Even with the code examples, I do not think they are clear about the benefits of choosing one or the other.

**What are the benefits of explicitly rendering reCAPTCHA widget as opposed to automatically rendering?**

Comment: There are some things that Google allows you to do when you load it manually, like setting the language. This I believe is not the case in automatic rendering. Also, based on performance aspects, a site may not want to load the captcha automatically and want the control with itself on when to load it. Is this what you were looking for ?

Comment: Sounds like an answer to me. Maybe add this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some things that Google allows you to do when you load it manually, like setting the language. This I believe is not the case in automatic rendering. Also, based on performance aspects, a site may not want to load the captcha automatically and want the control with itself on when to load it.

Answer (score 2):

When using js frameworks such as AngularJs ( or React ). The view template of the application may not be loaded yet when the recaptcha is loaded. Thus explicit rendering is needed.